# MathJax Equation Referencing using Jekyll Rendering Upon Click Error

Tags: markdown, jekyll, mathjax

Upon converting my Jupiter notebooks to Markdown to implement them in Jekyll, I am running into an issue with `MathJax` rendering of equation references. At first glance, the rendering seems fine. However, when one clicks on the equation reference, the page updates to show the TeX code of the equation. After researching this issue, I have arrived at no conclusion or fix to this. I'd be happy to include any code, but before I do, I wanted to see if anyone has seen this issue before. Hopefully, it is something minor that I am overlooking.

**First Rendering:**

[image: First Rendering]

**Rendering After Clicking Equation Reference:**

[image]

> And check the Github repository [here](https://github.com/saintlittle/ODEBook).

Comment: Note: Jupyter...it autocorrected before I noticed it.

Comment: Images are not helping to track this javascript error. A repository url can help.

Comment: Not a problem. https://github.com/saintlittle/ODEBook